# How to update my drupal launched sites

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I want to ask about how to update Drupal 7 sites. My site is divided into 2 phases, after launching and adding data in the first phase, I now want to update the second phase. I have a lot of new content type, Views and panels. I added a new language and blocks, a lot of things. I can export panel and view but what about the content type, language and any permission or configuration that saved into database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module to export *content types* and *permission*. You can go to *admin/structure/features/create* and the select the features you want to export.

Answer (score 2):

The [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module is your friend in deployment. However, there are some other things that are not supported by Features, and which require you to create an install script.